# Pick Oldest file on basis of date in Name of the file

Tags: bash, shell

I am stuck in one situation where I am having a bunch of files and I need to pick the oldest one on the basis of time present in name only. Not on basis of the timestamp as I am doing SCP from one system to another so timestamp would be same for all the files once SCP runs

I have files like

> 1. UAT-2019-03-21-16-31.csv
> 2. UAT-2019-03-21-17-01.csv
> 3. AIT-2019-03-21-17-01.csv

Here, 2019 represents the year, 03 the month, 21 the day, 16 the hours in 24-hour format and 31 represent the minutes.

I need to pick the `UAT-2019-03-21-16-31.csv` file from the above files first.
How can I do in shell scripting.

I tried doing `ls -1` but it will sort alphabetically, that means AIT-2019-03-21-17-01.csv will be picked first, but I need according to time mentioned in the file name

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
ls -1 | sort -t"-" -k2 -k3 -k4 -k5 -k6 | head -n1
```

Output :

```
UAT-2019-03-21-16-31.csv
```

Curious about alternatives answer as I know that parsing ls output is not ideal.

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*csv' -print0 | sort -z -t"-" -k2,6 | sed 's/\x00.*$//' ` (only GNU sort)

Answer (score 0):

The best and efficient way to do this would be to convert the filename time stamp to epoch time and find the oldest among them.

You need to write a script that does below in order:

1. Get all the filename timestamp into a variable.
2. Convert all filename timestamp to epoch time.
3. Find the oldest and get the filename.

Command to convert the filename timestamp to epoch time would be

```
date -d"2019-03-21T17:01" +%s
date -d"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM" +%s
```

You can try these steps in script

Hope so this helps you to start writing the script.